# Orientate automatically with tikz-uml

Tags: tikz-uml

Is there a way to define the position of components in tikz-uml automatically?

Normally it is necessary to set the position of an component as this example shows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \umlemptyclass{A1}
    \umlemptyclass[ x=3,y=−3]{A2}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If you don't define the position, the result would be, that the components are printed at the same position (x=0, y=0). Is there a way to create uml diagrams which components orientate automatically?

Comment: Maybe not exactly automatic positioning, but you can give name to a class with `\umlemptyclass[name = a]{A1}` for example. Then, with your second class, you specify the options `node distance = xcm` and position it at a given position with respect to `a` with, for example, the option `below right of = a`. A full example of your second class would be `\umlemptyclass[node distance = 3cm, below right of = a]{A2}`.

Comment: Hi @KersouMan, thank you yes I already saw that in the documentation. It is better than the normal way, but still not realy automatic.